# Having problems with _path in python script with "Module Not Found" even though they are present

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python3.8 on windows10, with Spyder4 and busy working through examples from DarwinEx about algo trading and how they do it but I've run into a basic issue. When I try and run the file in IPython it does not see the other files in the same directory that it is supposed to import. I know I am doing something wrong just not sure what. 
Have tried to hard code the path as you see in the image below and also tried another way as per a post her on SO.

I need to run the 'coin_flip_traders_v1.0.py' which then executes the errors.
Here it shows all files in the same directory.

```
In[65]: pwd
Out[65]: 'C:\\DNNTrain\\Coursera\\darwinex'

ls
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 544C-EAA4

 Directory of C:\DNNTrain\Coursera\darwinex

24/01/2020  11:24    <DIR>          .
24/01/2020  11:24    <DIR>          ..
23/01/2020  23:43    <DIR>          __pycache__
24/01/2020  11:24             9,700 coin_flip_traders_v1.0.py
24/01/2020  10:14    <DIR>          DarwinexLabs-master
24/01/2020  09:47             5,101 DWX_HISTORY_IO_v2_0_1_RC8.py
23/01/2020  22:25            26,718 DWX_ZeroMQ_Connector_v2_0_1_RC8.py
24/01/2020  09:47            35,491 DWX_ZeroMQ_Server_v2.0.1_RC8.mq4
24/01/2020  09:47             2,195 DWX_ZMQ_Execution.py
24/01/2020  09:47             1,928 DWX_ZMQ_Reporting.py
24/01/2020  11:23             2,219 DWZ_ZMQ_Strategy.py
24/01/2020  11:10    <DIR>          EXAMPLES
               7 File(s)         83,352 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  116,616,744,960 bytes free
```

Tis is the part in the code that it calls.

```
import os
#_path = 'C:\\DNNTrain\\Coursera\\darwinex\\' # Tried this with no luck
_path = './' # Also not working
os.chdir(_path)

#from EXAMPLES.TEMPLATE.STRATEGIES.BASE.DWX_ZMQ_Strategy import DWX_ZMQ_Strategy
from DWX_ZMQ_Strategy import DWX_ZMQ_Strategy
```

Here is the command and output I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\DNNTrain\Coursera\darwinex\coin_flip_traders_v1.0.py", line 47, in <module>
    from DWX_ZMQ_Strategy import DWX_ZMQ_Strategy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DWX_ZMQ_Strategy'
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Also tried `#_path = 'C:/DNNTrain/Coursera/darwinex'
#os.chdir(_path)
os.chdir(r"C:\DNNTrain\Coursera\darwinex")` as per the documentation, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before hanging myself I saw that I copied all the files into the same directory and provided the _path correctly, but I never thought that they would have a typo in their file name. In the ls above you can see it is "DWZ...." instead it should be "DWX..." as per the call from the script and all the other files. 
Guess Z and X are indeed very close to each other.

Lesson learned: Analysis paralysis - couldn't think that it would be so simple.